# setting current date/time in process builder

Tags: datetime, process-builder

I'm trying to figure out if process builder can update a field to the current date/time when the criteria is meet.

I want to track when an opportunity stage is selected.  I know the tracking in down in the stage history however I need to have it on the detailed page.

I've tried $GlobalConstant.now, $GlobalConstant.now()... not sure if this is able.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a variable that would allow you to do this directly in the Process Builder. There are two workarounds that i am aware of:

1. Create a formula field on the Process object set equal to Now() and use this to set the value.
2. Create a record update or insert Quick Action on the Target Object and use the pre-defined values to set your desired field to Now(). This is my preferred option as you can use the pre-defined values in the quick action manage all of your field updates while using the familiar formula builder UI.
3. Set the Target field equal to the Last Modified Date of the Source object. This will get you within a few seconds of Now() since the Process is triggered after the insert/update.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  sometimes simple logic as this just don't come to mind instantly....

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before this is not available at this time.  It was mentioned to use Visual Work Flow which is a viable work around.

That said I came up with my own solution: Create a formula field which is the formula of "now."  Then in Process Builder just use the "Now" field to set the date/time.

Answer (score 1):

There is an idea for this [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DfJxAAK) (unfortunately!).

Comment: Yes added my vote.. however I came up with a hack solution.