# Formula Fields in Process Builder

Tags: datetime, process-builder

I was trying to replicate the workaround for not being able to put a Now formula into a Process Builder action as found here: [setting current date/time in process builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70046/setting-current-date-time-in-process-builder)

I created a formula field with Now() on my Account object but it doesn't show up in the process builder as a selectable field. A test blank Text field does show up, so is there are problem with using date fields in process builder? How were people able to get this workaround to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your formula result to Date vs Date/Time and it should allow you to pick the field. I tested this out in my Dev org and noticed the Task Due Date is Date Only. So you may need to have your formula result in Date only.

P.S. just read a blog post that they are making this available in summer 25. [summer 15 treasure hunt](http://www.salesforceweek.ly/2015/04/process-builder-summer-15-treasure-hunt.html)

Comment: Oh wow that's a big update, that'll be great.

Comment: This new adition will make process builder really powerful. [And you can open your summer 15 org already](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-summer15.jsp)!